# Refactor method (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, methods, refactoring

I have got method:

```
private bool MyMethod(PlantType plantType)
{
    return plantType.PlantMoveType == PlantMoveType.PlantReady 
           || plantType.PlantMoveType == PlantMoveType.PlantRelase
}
```

Can I write it into other way? Maybe with LINQ?

Comment: What's wrong with the current way? Do you want to shorten it or something?

Comment: What other way do you mean? the only other thing i can think of is `private bool MyMethod(PlantType plantType) => new [] { PlantMoveType.PlantReady, PlantMoveType.PlantRelase}.Contains(plantType.PlantMoveType);`

Comment: as example LINQ is so popular now I want to know how can I use it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to put the enum values that you want to check against into an array, and call `Contains`.

```
return new[] { PlantMoveType.PlantReady, PlantMoveType.PlantRelase }
                 .Contains(plantType.PlantMoveType);
```

If you are using C# 7 or later, you can also write the method as [expression-bodied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members):

```
private bool MyMethod(PlantType plantType) =>
    new[] { PlantMoveType.PlantReady, PlantMoveType.PlantRelase }
        .Contains(plantType.PlantMoveType);
```

Comment: thank you @Sweeper for quick answer, I will try to use your first hint

Answer (score 0):

Well a small simplification would be to pass the type (enum?) of the property `PlantMoveType` instead of `PlantType` as the parameter.

Beyond that, you could declare the types to check for as e.g. an array. In case you'd like to reuse that array, you can also declare it outside the scope of the method:

```
private static PlantMoveType[] _plantStates = 
   new []{PlantMoveType.PlantReady, PlantMoveType.PlantRelase};

private bool MyMethod(PlantMoveType plantMoveType)
{
    return _plantStates.Contains(plantMoveType);
}
```